# Плейлисты и проигрывание музыки на сайте

Tags: javascript, ajax

Добрый день.
Подскажите, каким образом реализовать что-то подобное проигрыванию музыки на сайте и плейлисты пользователя как тут: http://tidido.com/ru/RU
На данный момент есть скрипт, позволяющий запустить музыку в фоновом режиме, при переходах по страницам все работает, а как его адаптировать под вышеозначенную задачу.

```
$$r(function() {
  $$i({
      create:'script',
      attribute: {
        'type':'text/javascript',
        'src':'http://nagon.net/modules/NRMSLib/NRMSLib.js'
      },
      insert:$$().body,
      onready:function() {//выполняю только после загрузки скрипта
        $$e.add($$('mp3button'),'click',playmp3rand);//добавляю событие кнопке после загрузки скрипта
    }
  });
});

var playmp3rand = function (event) {
    //запукаю случайную музыку
    modules.sound.stop();//останавливаю если что то уже играет
    switch($$s.randnum(1,3)) {//случайное число от 1 до 3 включительно
        case 1:
            modules.sound.start({'music': 'http://goldenland.onfind.net/2/1/'+$$s.randnum(1,8)+'.mp3'});
        break;
        case 2:
            modules.sound.start({'music': 'http://goldenland.onfind.net/2/2/'+$$s.randnum(1,12)+'.mp3'});
        break;
        case 3:
            modules.sound.start({'music': 'http://goldenland.onfind.net/2/3/'+$$s.randnum(1,4)+'.mp3'});
        break;
    }
    $$('sound_s_el_m').$$('width','1px').$$('height','1px').$$('overflow','hidden');//эти параметры трогать не нужно
}
```

Comment: Точно так же, как и на приведенном по ссылке сайте. Добавить нужные data-* атрибуты к тегам и при клике считывать из них информацию о проигрываемой музыке. Остается только подставить считанную ссылку в ваш модуль.

Comment: Я вижу у них data-id="sport" - проигрывается музыка из определенного раздела (sport)/ Таким образом, я с помощью data- могу подсунуть скрипту нужную информацию о том, какую музыку запустить?

Comment: Да, с помощью data-* атрибутов можно прикреплять и потом считывать информацию и подсовывать скрипту. Учитывая, что в data-* вместо * можно написать все, что захочется(data-id="bla-bla", data-music="bla-bla", data-fuuuuuu="bla-bla"), предоставляется большой выбор использования. Остается только их сгенерировать где-нибудь на сервере.

Comment: У меня тут образовалась другая проблема - музон хранить у себя на сервере не смогу - нужны большие мощности)) Но вот через api ВК можно получить ссылку на трек, и вот как этот url подставить? Ответ такой идет от него response: [{
 id: 145228616,
 owner_id: 126110704,
 artist: 'Nirvana',
 title: 'Smells Like Teen Spirit',
 duration: 301,
 url: 'http://cs9-4v4.vk.../01a07936d18bc3.mp3',
 lyrics_id: 94933876,
 genre_id: 1
}]